# ActiveRecord connection not established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I used this command to create an app    rails new guestbook

then i used :-

```
rails generate scaffold Person name:string
```

and in routes.rb i unhashed the `root :to => 'people#index'`

then I wrote in the address bar localhost:3000/people and I got the following error :-

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
Rails.root: /home/rudraksha/rbtest/gbook
```

please answer ASAP

Comment: Update the question along with rails with all the steps you did..create project and all ..??

Answer (score 2):

Anyways, the problem is that, connection is unable to establish with database.

Have you configured you database.yml as per you database? If not you have to configure it first.

If you are using mysql, you have to install `mysql` gem by adding it to your gemfile and running `bundle install` and configure database.yml accordingly.

Example of database.yml with mysql:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: <db_name>
  pool: 5
  username: <your_mysql_username>
  password: <your_mysql_password>
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: <db_name>
  pool: 5
  username: <your_mysql_username>
  password: <your_mysql_password>
  host: localhost
```